# How to use Lodash Debounce on resize

Tags: lodash

I'm trying to trigger an event on resize of window, it seems like it does not work.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   _.debounce(function(){
       console.log("hello");
   }, 100);
})
```

Comment: `_.debounce` returns a function, and you have to call it.

Answer (score 8):

It's actually shown in their lodash documentation as an example, [lodash#debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce):

```js
$(window).on('resize', _.debounce(function() {
  console.log('resized!');
}, 100));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 7):

Vanilla JS in case:

```
window.onresize = _.debounce(() => {
  console.log('resized!')
}, 100)
```

EDIT: Actually probably better to use event listener instead:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', _.debounce(() => {
  console.log('resized!')
}, 100)
```

Comment: @b00t not sure what the downvote/confusion is for, the OP asks how to trigger lodash debounce on resize, not how to implement debounce in pure vanilla js. In case that is of interest, this post explains it well https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function along with looking at what lodash implements directly https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/36eef3c118041ae6386b6bba2b48b099e57ca0e5/underscore.js#L883 - this was merely to mention how to satisfy OP's request without jQuery

Comment: Totally my bad, must've been tired when I looked through this. Removed my original comment, so that it won't push anyone in the wrong direction.